# Passing variables to LatLngBounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, casting

I am trying to pass variables to google.maps.LatLngBounds, but it doesnt work. the only thing that seems to work is if I hard code the numbers as floats (literals) If I try what is below it fails. I have tried every way of casting, but it just will not display. The example below is the last thing I have tried.

I am geocoding the center from an address and attempting to create an overlay that surrounds the center so the image overlay will always be behind the center.

```
var x1 = (parseFloat(xLat) - 0.0003).toFixed(6);
var y1 = (parseFloat(yLon) + 0.0003).toFixed(6);
var x2 = (parseFloat(xLat) + 0.0003).toFixed(6);
var y2 = (parseFloat(yLon) - 0.0003).toFixed(6);
var coordinates1 = x1 + "," + y1;
var coordinates2 = x1 + "," + y1;
        var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
           new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(coordinates1.split(",")[0]), parseFloat(coordinates1.split(",")[1]) ), //sw
           new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(coordinates2.split(",")[0]), parseFloat(coordinates2.split(",")[1]) )  //ne
        );
```

Any ideas why this fails? I know there are other questions that are similar, and none of those solutions worked. I think I have tried them all, literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google.maps.LatLng class Constructor LatLng(lat:number, lng:number) [**Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

```
var x1 = xLat - 0.0003;
var y1 = yLon - 0.0003;//Was + 1 in Question & Origonal Answer
var x2 = xLat + 0.0003;
var y2 = yLon + 0.0003;//Was - 1 in Question & Origonal Answer

var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng( x1, y1), //sw
          new google.maps.LatLng( x2, y2) //ne
        );
```

**EDIT** Changed y1 & y2 in response to Michael's Comment and Answer as they were wrong

Comment: so I did try that, I thought the difference was using the constructor (`new google.maps.LatLng( x1, y1)`), but what you showed was the first thing I tried. It does work if i use  something like this: new google.maps.LatLng( 40.000000, -70.000000)

Comment: Are you just inverting values? SW lat and lng should be lower than NE lat and lng, except if the limits are included.

Comment: These calculations wouldn't change depending on whether the original coordinates are negative or positive. (I'm conveniently ignoring the case where you're straddling the 180 meridian, but it's true otherwise at least.)

Answer (score 3):

Just a followup to David's fine answer, posting this as an answer instead of a comment because I can't do code formatting in a comment.

Instead of names like `x1`, let's use names that correspond to the terminology in the Maps API. For starters, I'm going to rename `xLat` as `lat` and `yLon` as `lng`, and then we'll go from there. Also we'll do it step by step for clarity:

```
var s = lat - 0.0003;
var w = lng - 0.0003;
var n = lat + 0.0003;
var e = lng + 0.0003;

var sw = new google.maps.LatLng( s, w );
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng( n, e );

var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( sw, ne );
```

Notice how we ended up fixing a bug here, simply because the names are now more clear. South is always less than North, and West is always less than East (ignoring the 180 meridian). With the `x1` style names, it wasn't clear which was which, and a bug snuck into the code where North (`y2`) was *less* than South (`y1`). That's easy to have happen when your variable names aren't meaningful.

Another interesting point is that the code no longer needs the `// sw` and `// ne` comments. In fact, even if you go back to a style where the `sw` and `ne` variables aren't used, it's still clear which is the southwest and which is the northeast:

```
var s = lat - 0.0003;
var w = lng - 0.0003;
var n = lat + 0.0003;
var e = lng + 0.0003;

var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng( s, w ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( n, e )
);
```

Note how those comments would still be unnecessary here.

Don't get me wrong, I'm all for good comments, but when you can use a meaningful variable name *instead* of a comment, that's a real improvement.

Comment: good poits, simple and direct is always better. looks like the underlying math was my issue all along. thanks both of you.